# To find kernel of $\rho:\mathbb{Z}[G^2] \to \mathbb{Z}[G/H]$, where $\rho((g_1,g_2))=Hg_2-Hg_1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, tensor-products, group-cohomology

I am reading Theorem $2.1$ of the paper [The Volume and Chern-Simons Invariant of a Representation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2049.pdf). I ran into a problem in proving the last part of it, i.e., to prove that the cokernel of the map $F_2 \to F_1$ is $K$.

Here I am trying to describe the problem in a simple form, and I think anyone can understand it without going through the proof of Theorem $2.1$.

> If $X$ is any set, then denote $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ to be the free abelian group generated over the set $X$. Let $G$ be a group and $H$ its subgroup and define a group homomorphism $\rho: \mathbb{Z}[G^2] \to \mathbb{Z}[G/H]$ as $\rho(n(g_1,g_2))= nHg_2 -nHg_1.$ What is the $\ker(\rho)$?

As per the requirement of the proof of Theorem $2.1$ and if my calculations are correct then the kernel must be generated by the following set
$\{ (hg,g) - (g_2g,g) +(g_1g,g) -(g_1 g_2^{-1}g,g)~|~ g_1,g_2,g \in G, ~h\in H\}.$

I don't know why $Hg_2g-Hg_1g-Hg + Hg_1g_2 ^{-1}g=0$.

Can someone help me in proving this?

Comment: Is H normal in G or is G/H simply the set of cosets?

Comment: Your generating seems weird to me. First $g$ is not on the list of variables on the right, but that is not very important. More to the point, when $m'=0$ and $m=1$, the element is very clearly not in the kernel. Also, what is the point of $h_1$ and $h_2$ when obviously they could be replaced by any $h\in H$, or even just by $1$?

Comment: user622002: $G/H$ is simply the set of cosets. $H$ need not be normal.

Comment: Lama: As per your observations, I have made changes to the question. Moreover, the point that taking $m=1, m'=0$ is right. Let me check my calculations.  And I think taking $h=1$ will change the generating set.

Comment: Lama: I have asked a question related to this question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536583/to-find-image-of-map-c-1h-h-c-2g-g-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbzg.